# org-mode captions not supported for EXAMPLE blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Please consider the following, self-contained `.org` file MVE, which I hope is self-explanatory:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

Figure [[captions-work-for-src-blocks]] shows that captions are correctly exported
for SRC blocks. The second figure, in an EXAMPLE block, does not receive an
exported caption. Furthermore, cross references to figure
[[captions-dont-work-for-example-blocks]] incorrectly resolve to figure
[[captions-work-for-src-blocks]].

-----
#+NAME: captions-work-for-src-blocks
#+CAPTION: Captions work for SRC blocks
#+BEGIN_SRC
  foo(bar) == baz(qux);
#+END_SRC
-----

-----
#+NAME: captions-dont-work-for-example-blocks
#+CAPTION: Captions don't work for EXAMPLE blocks
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
  foo(bar) == baz(qux);
#+END_EXAMPLE
-----
```

On `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, it produces the following output:

[image]

I'm using the following versions of the software:

```
: Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))
:  of 2016-09-17
: org version: 9.0.7
```

I looked at the official org-mode documentation, but I could not find information relating to this issue.

Comment: Seems related https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-04/msg00877.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By trial and error (and by digging into the suggestion by @Hatshepsut), I discovered that the following works:

```
#+begin_example
/usr/local/share/guile/site/2.2$ tree math/
math/
`-- bessel.scm
#+end_example
#+latex: \caption{Directory structure for Guile extension module}
```

whereas the following does NOT work:

```
#+caption: Directory structure for Guile extension module
#+begin_example
/usr/local/share/guile/site/2.2$ tree math/
math/
`-- bessel.scm
#+end_example
```

For `src` blocks and for `results` output, I am currently using the following because `#+caption` does not work on `#+RESULTS` blocks, just as it does not work on `#+begin_example` (no idea whether this pattern is optimal):

```
#+caption: How to find out where Guile expects to find extension modules
#+begin_src scheme :exports both
(%site-dir)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /usr/local/share/guile/site/2.2
#+latex: \caption{This is the answer that Guile gives, live in org-babel}
```

Iirc, there is some mention of captioning `#+RESULTS` blocks somewhere in the org-mode manual. I have not been able to find it a second time. The following link is a bit vague:

```
https://orgmode.org/manual/Captions.html
```

In no cases have I yet tried org-mode `name`, nor LaTeX `label` and `ref`.